# Ruby on Rails Bootstrap SASS to LESS Conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am migrating Boostrap 2.3 to Boostrap 3.0. Boostrap 3.0 uses LESS instead of SASS.

Is there any good guides out there for syntax differences between the two for custom.css.scss?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has an [official Sass port](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). There are also some gems, like [this one](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

Source: [Bootstrap Site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#sass)